# How do I create a button in Emacs?

Tags: help, buttons

I'm trying to create `*Help*` buffers in Emacs, documenting functions defined in other languages.

I can create a simple help buffer easily:

```
(defun wh/help-hello-world ()
  (interactive)
  (with-help-window (help-buffer)
    (princ "foo_bar is a function.\n\nIt does stuff.")))
```

However, I want to add a clickable link in my `*Help*` buffer, which Emacs seems to call a button. I can see `describe-function-1` calls `help-xref-button` which creates a button.

However, if I call `insert-text-button` the same way `help-xref-button` creates buttons, then `'help-args` seems to expect an elisp function and path.

```
(defun wh/help-hello-world-button ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (help-buffer)))
    (with-help-window buf
      (princ "foo_bar is a function.\n\nIt does stuff."))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (insert-text-button
         "example.txt"
         'type 'help-function-def
         'help-args '(button-type-subtype-p "/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/button.el.gz"))))))
```

How can I create an Emacs button pointing to an arbitrary line in an arbitrary file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use both `make-button` or `make-text-button`. For example

```
(defun button-pressed (button)
  (message (format "Button pressed!")))

(define-button-type 'custom-button
  'action 'button-pressed
  'follow-link t
  'help-echo "Click Button"
  'help-args "test")

(make-button 1 10 :type 'custom-button)
```

This will create a button at char 1 to 10 in the current buffer.

Comment: Works really well! Is the `'help-args` value actually used anywhere?

Comment: Aha, it can be accessed using `button-get`.